# npmignore .sh files in all but one directory

Tags: node.js, npm, gitignore, npmignore

I'd like to ignore all the .sh files in a project, except for the ones located in a particular directory, let's call the directory foo.

so we have:

```
project/
   bar.sh
   baz.sh
   foo/
     a.sh
     b.sh
```

I don't want to publish `bar.sh` and `baz.sh` to NPM, but I *do* want to publish `a.sh` and `b.sh` to NPM. It turns out I have a number of .sh files outside of the foo directory, and it would be more convenient to ignore all of them in one fell swoop.

What can I add to my `.npmignore` file that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the docs for [.npmignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) it states:

> `.npmignore` files follow the [same pattern rules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files) as `.gitignore` files:

In which case you ignore all the `.sh` files (i.e. `*.sh`) then negate that pattern using the apostrophe `!` and specify the folder name that you want to include. For example:

**Example 1**

```
# ignore all .sh files
*.sh

# include .sh files in the folder foo
!foo/*.sh
```

Using this configuration, *(within the context of the example folder structure shown below)*,  all these files are ignored: `a.sh`, `b.sh`, `e.sh`, `f.sh`

The following files are included/published: `c.sh` and `d.sh`.

Note: `e.sh` and `f.sh` are ignored too using this config as they're in a sub folder.

---

**Example 2**

To also include/publish the `.sh` files in any sub folders of the folder `foo` then configure your `.npmignore` as follows:

```
# ignore all .sh files
*.sh

# include .sh files in the folder foo and any inside its sub folders
!foo/**/*.sh
```

Using this configuration, *(within the context of the example folder structure shown below)*,  only files: `a.sh` and `b.sh` are ignored. All other `.sh` files are published.

---

**Example folder structure**

```
project
├── a.sh
├── b.sh
└── foo
    ├── baz
    │   ├── e.sh
    │   └── f.sh
    ├── c.sh
    └── d.sh
```